# Bitmap deleted but still visible?

Tags: c#, image, file

I have a function which return `BitmapImage`:

```
    private BitmapImage dfa2bmp(DFA dfa)
    {
        //[...]
        //myGraph.png generated here[...]
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.BeginInit();
        bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bmp.UriSource = new Uri(graphvizDir + "\\myGraph.png");
        bmp.EndInit();
        File.Delete(graphvizDir + "\\myGraph.png");

        return bmp;
    }
```

So after each invocation, the file myGraph.png is different. However, when I assign the return value of `dfa2bmp` to an Image control, I still get the old image, even though it was deleted during the previous call to my function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;` This line is caching the image in RAM and then it's being displayed from there. The docs say;

*Caches the entire image into memory at load time. All requests for image data are filled from the memory store.*

If you want to prevent the program from using the image after it's deleted change the BitmapCacheOption to none. so; `bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;` will do what you want.

EDIT: I don't know what side effects this will have, I don't really deal with these libraries but I see some potential for an exception when you try to assign the deleted image to your image control. I think a better solution may be to set the object to `null` which will cause the GC to free the memory containing the image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `BitmapCreateOptions` to `IgnoreImageCache`.

```
  bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
```

You use `BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache` when you have a image that needs to be refreshed

> ```
>     // Summary:
>     //     Loads images without using an existing image cache. This option should only
>     //     be selected when images in a cache need to be refreshed.
>     IgnoreImageCache = 8,
> ```